# android invalid key hash. The key hash does not match any stored key hashes

Tags: android, facebook, hash, api-key

I am new one in android I applied Facebook login in my app i generated app Key from Facebook and put package and ActivityName in Facebook app generated also put Key Hash but when deployed to play store and download and run than showing erro

> "Invalid key hash. The key hash does not match any stored key hashes."

Comment: post your code and full error

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in your `MainActivity`

```
try {
    PackageInfo info = getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
            "your package name here",
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    }
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In `logcat` you will get `KeyHash` printed. copy that and paste in you facebook developer account's application's `keyhash` list.

and let me know if it works.